# Get Process Information After Termination

Tags: python, linux, process, popen, pid

I need some information about one *child* process **after termination**.

Such as `utime` and `VMPeak` in `/proc` like this:

```
proc.wait()
with open('/proc/%d/stat' % proc.pid, "r") as f:
    stat = str(f.read()).strip().split()
    # 14th column is utime, 15th column is stime (man 5 proc)                  
    cpu_time = int(stat[14]) + int(stat[15])
    return cpu_time
```

But Python `Popen.wait()` released `PID`, so I will get:

```
No such file or directory
```

Can I get that **after termination**, or **wait** for termination **without** releasing `PID` ? (I mean wait for termination **without** invoke `wait()` which will release all resource.)

I'd be grateful if you could help me. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a problem about python but Linux programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from `man 5 proc`:

> `/proc/[pid]`
>   There is a numerical subdirectory for each **running process**; the subdirectory is named by the process ID.

A terminated process is *no longer running*, and its `/proc/[pid]` directory (including the `stat` file), is *no longer going to be there*.

If it was going to be there, you can just store the PID in a variable *before* you call `proc.wait()`:

```
pid = proc.pid
proc.wait()
with open('/proc/%d/stat' % pid, "r") as f:
```

There is no 'just before termination' event; `subprocess` waits, then reaps the exit code.

You could do your own waiting with [`os.wait4()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.wait4) instead:

```
pid, status, resources = os.wait4(proc.pid, 0)
cpu_time = resources.ru_utime + resources.ru_stime
```

`resources` is a named tuple, see [`resource.getrusage()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html#resource.getrusage) for a list of what names it supports. Both `.ru_utime` and `.ru_stime` are floating point values.

Comment: So I need a way to wait for termination without wait() ;-). Save PID is not useful because if I wait() the PID will be release and then no /proc there.

Comment: /proc will be remained for zombie processes which have not been wait().

Comment: Zombie processes are still terminated; the OS does retain the proc info then, yes, but only because there are still child processes that depend on the parent PID. Are you trying to track a zombie process here?

Comment: I just want a way to get some information after termination or 0.00001 second before termination. ;-)

Comment: That is what my answer tells you is not possible. After termination, *usually* the proc info is gone, and there is no notification given just before termination.

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to say. I'm tracking my child process.

Comment: I mean I need a way to wait for termination without invoke wait() which will release all resource.

Comment: @JasonLau: sorry, I found a way anyway.